# Formula using R[1]C[1]-style written by vba doesn't refer to the correct cells

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a simple macro in Excel 2016 that finds a certain value in a column and enters formulas into a different column, starting in the row of the found value.

```
Set Target = OutputSht.Range(OutputSht.Cells(4, 2), _
            OutputSht.Cells(100, 2)).Find(ValueToBeFound)

'set the formula of cells in columns 5
OutputSht.Cells(Target.Row, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-12]C[-2]-RC[-2]"

'set formulas in all relevant cells below that
OutputSht.Range(OutputSht.Cells(Target.Row + 1, 5), _
            OutputSht.Cells(100, 5)).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=R[-1]C*(RC[-2]/R[-1]C[-2])"
```

With OutputSht being the codename of a sheet.

This code works most of the time, but every so often it will insert completely wrong references. If the Target Cell the is e.g. is E17, the formula `"=R[-12]C[-2]-RC[-2]"` should refer to Cells C4 and C17. However, sometimes the formula written by the macro is `=XFC1048565-XFC1`. Looking closer at the issue, I figured out that what happens is that the relative reference essentially pretends to be written in Cell A1, and moving up and/or left from the cell will make the reference loop around and end up close to the last row/column in the sheet. The Cell holding the formula is the correct one though, in this example Cell E17 (this is interesting btw, as when I intentionally tried doing this loop-around, it threw an error).

I haven't been able to determine what causes this to happen (it doesn't make a difference if OutputSht is the active Sheet or not), but most of the time it works correctly.

While I can work around the issue by entering hard to interpret formulas containing several IFs into the cells, I might need to write formulas with a macro in the future. As currently I can't really trust this method, I'd like to know if there is a fix to this and what causes it. Is this a known issue? (I haven't been able to find anything online). Is it a bug? Is there a mistake in my code?

Edit: I replaced every instance of `.formula` with `.formulaR1C1` (also in the question). The issue persists - still only occasionally, but the messed up references still happen.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `...FormulaR1C1`?

Comment: ^^ Using `Formula` and just hoping that Excel will guess that you meant to use R1C1 notation is dangerous (e.g. does `C5` refer to cell `C5` or to the column `E:E`).  Always use `FormulaR1C1` when specifying formulas using R1C1 notation and only use `Formula` when specifying formulas using A1 notation.  However, I am surprised that the formulas that you showed would be misinterpreted.  (P.S.  Are your two `Range`s missing closing brackets??)

Comment: @Bruce ... I suppose I should. `.Formula` seems to generally be working the same, however. I'll change it and see if the issue persists. Thanks.

Comment: hmm a Wednesday question on a Tuesday :] `.Formula` is for A1 reference style and `.FormulaR1C1` for R1C1 reference

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for the explanation, I read about `.formula` and `.formulaR1C1` before, but never had it explained that clearly and concisely. (And yes, they did. I edited the modified the code a bit after copying it over and deleted the brackets on accident. Well spotted.)

Comment: @Slai You're obviously living in the past - it's Wednesday in the **real** world!